How to conditionally change a cell's text alignment and font color?
I have a data validation list in D12:D2000 with Income, Expenses, and Savings. In F12:F2000 I enter my amounts. I have it so the font color in column F changes according to column D. Example: If D12 is 'Income', the font in F12 changes to green. If it's 'Savings' in D13, F13's font color changes to blue, etc. These work.
What I want to accomplish is, for the range F12:F2000:

If D12 is 'Income', F12's font is green and center aligned.
If D12 is 'Expenses', F12's font is red and right aligned.
If D12 is 'Savings', F12's font is blue and left aligned.

How do I accomplish this?

Hi David, which program are you using? (i.e. MS Excel, Google Sheets etc)
